# R dataframe filter and count unique entries

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe such as:

```
A    B    C    D  
1    1    1    1  
1    1    1    1  
2    2    1    2  
2    2    2    2  
2    2    1    2
```

And I want to create a dataframe that only has the unique entries and the count of how many times it occurred. So something like this:

```
A    B    C    D    count
1    1    1    1     2  
2    2    1    2     2   
2    2    2    2     1
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the "data.table" package, like this:

```
> library(data.table)
> as.data.table(dat)[, .N, by = names(dat)]
   A B C D N
1: 1 1 1 1 2
2: 2 2 1 2 2
3: 2 2 2 2 1
```

Or similarly with "dplyr":

```
> library(dplyr)
> dat %>% group_by_(.dots = names(dat)) %>% summarise(n = n())
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
Groups: A, B, C

  A B C D n
1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 1 2 2
3 2 2 2 2 1
```

Comment: brilliant! thanks so much. You saved me from having to mindlessly finding the length of each combination of the levels.

Answer (score 3):

A `base R` option is

```
aggregate(cbind(Count=1:nrow(df1))~., df1, FUN=length)
#    A B C D Count
#  1 1 1 1 1     2
#  2 2 2 1 2     2
#  3 2 2 2 2     1
```

Or a modification suggested by @David Arenburg

```
aggregate(Count ~ ., cbind(Count = 1, df1), FUN=length)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Never seen this before.

Comment: Note that the value of the added column `Count` is not used in the aggregate.

Comment: Yes, I saw what happened

Comment: @MatthewLundberg  Yes, it is just a place-holder to get the length.

Comment: My base approach was to use `rownames` with `aggregate` or to use `unique(cbind(dat, count = ave(rep(1, nrow(dat)), dat, FUN = length)))`.

Comment: Yes, maybe `aggregate(Count ~ ., cbind(Count = 1, df1), length)` will be a bit more readable?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.